# Storing a list from form to database as an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to load a multi numbers(rows) to a database from a form. Anyone can help with the code?

```
$n = $_POST['txtname'];

foreach ($a as $value) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO Sheet1 VALUES($value)";
```

Comment: Please use programming language markup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise an array with the data before using the foreach loop.

You should use the following format:

```
//Obtain values from form text boxes
$name = $_POST['Name'] //This must match the name input on your form

//Populate values into array
$arrayData = array('$name');  //Can also populate with multiple values..

//Query
foreach ($arrayData as $value) {
    $sql = "INSERT into table_name (table_column_name) VALUES($value)";
}
```

Sources: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

http://bbrown.kennesaw.edu/papers/php2.html